# Unable to import .xls - Symfony PHP

Tags: php, excel, symfony, import, xls

I am a new developer working at a company on a website. We have a bug with importing excel files, it does not accept xls as a valid extention, but xlsx and others are accepted. Here is the method that gives the error.

public function orderAddUpload(Request $request){

```
    /*
    Filepath: /web/uploads/files/{entity_name}/{entity_id}/{filename}
     */

    $response = array();

    $entity = $request->request->get('upload_entity');
    $id     = $request->request->get('upload_id');
    $user   = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $valid_ext = array( 'doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'pdf', 'txt', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png' );

    $file = $request->files->get('files');
    if( is_array($file) ) $file = reset( $file );


    try{
        if( empty($file) ){
            throw new Exception($this->get('translator')->trans('upload.failure'), 1);
        }

        if( ! in_array($file->guessExtension(), $valid_ext) ){
            throw new Exception($this->get('translator')->trans('file.invalid.extension')." (" . $file->guessExtension() . "), ".$this->get('translator')->trans('only')." ".implode( ', ', $valid_ext ) . " ".$this->get('translator')->trans('are.accepted').".", 2);
        }

        $upload = new Upload();
        $upload
            ->setFiletype( $file->guessExtension() )
            ->setEntityName( $entity )
            ->setEntityId( $id )
            ->setUploader( $user );

        $name    = basename( $file->getClientOriginalName(),  '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension() );
        $ext     = $file->guessExtension();
        $counter = 1;

        $newname = "{$name}.{$ext}";

        while( file_exists($newname) ){
            $newname = "{$name}_{$counter}.{$ext}";
            $counter++;
        }

        $upload->setFilename( $newname );

        $file->move( $upload->getFilePath(), $upload->getFilename() );

        $em->persist( $upload );
        $em->flush();


    }catch(Exception $e){
        return new Response( json_encode(array( 'type' => 'error', 'message' => $e->getMessage(), )) );
    }

    $response['code'] = 'uploaded';

    return new Response( json_encode($response) );
}
```

As far as I can tell, when I try to import an xls file it returns the extension as NULL instead of as xls and throws the Exception'file.invalid.extension'.

I dont understand why this is happening because xls is one of the exentions defined as valid in the $valid_ext array. All other extensions in that array are imported without problem. I dug into the guessExtension method and further in guessMimeType which it uses, but everything seems to be working fine in those.

When I comment out the Exception'file.invalid.extension' and try to import the xls file the error I get tells me that the file type column cannot be NULL, something to do with SQL.

If anyone knows anything about this type of problem please let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might look at this in the future, I found the problem. Basically the xls mime type in Symfony is out of date and wrong. guessExtension calls on guessMimeType to figure out the mime type of the file imported, and then guessExtension uses the mime type returned by guessMimeType to guess an extension. The guessExtension method references a list of mime types to do so, and the proble was that the xls mime type in that list was wrong, most likely just outdated. I found the current xls mime type and replaced the one in the list by the good one and it worked

Comment: You mention you found correct mime type, which one is it then?

Answer (score 0):

Use `getExtension()` method instead of `guessExtension()`. `getExtension()` returns extension of a file based on its name, while the other method returns file extension based on mime type.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have mentioned that I already tried getExtension as well and unfortunetly got the same results.